# Opening SQLite .db from assets

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Somehow I've got an error of copying a .db file in Log (as you see log in the code)
The napoleon.db file is in the assets folder, so as I assume everything should work, but it doesn't

Why doesn't it find it?

I'm doing it by example, but it doesn't work.
Any thoughts?

```
public class MySqLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "napoleon.db";
    public final static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.task/databases/";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
    private final Context dbContext;

    public MySqLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.dbContext = context;
        // checking database and open it if exists
        if (checkDataBase()) {
            openDataBase();
        } else
        {
            try {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                copyDataBase();
                this.close();
                openDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "Initial database is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        InputStream myInput = dbContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String dbPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        dataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        boolean exist = false;
        try {
            String dbPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.v("MyLog", "database does't exist");
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            exist = true;
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return exist;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: whats the error in logcat?

Comment: Error copying database

Comment: do some research first ... and use https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this DB Path:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
   DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";         
}
else
{
   DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
}
```

For Jellybean 4.2 multi users change:

`DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";`

to:

`DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";`

Comment: well, the problem is different - instead of list of tables it returns only android_metadata. I'll accept yours because the paths are correct

Comment: It seems like the db is not returning tables. Instead of it says that table name is android_metadata .

Comment: well, it's strange, I just uninstalled app and reinstalled it and the problem is gone. The whole problem, half of day to research, the downvoted question solved only with uninstalling app.. brilliant :(

Comment: would you please give me a little help because I'm not familiar with quiery? I got this : Cursor c = db.query("Org", null, null, null, null, null, null); but also need to add to selecting table named "Org" following: Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT "+ id + " AS _id") because SimpleAdapter need to have an _id field nesessarily for some reason. How do I combine this 2 into one quiery?

Answer (score -1):

Use below post learn line by line step to copy db from asset to app memory

http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/11/copy-sqlite-database-file-from-assets.html

Comment: You mean, my question? or you meant answer by this person?  Because I didn't upvote

Comment: @user2976267 . that guys deleted his comment now